# Why isn't my code working inside a function I created, but works when I run it in the global environment?

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe "fish8" and I tried writing a function that excludes all empty rows for three of the dataframe's columns (BIN, collectors, country). The thing is the code isn't being run inside the function, but it runs outside of it. I have many other similar functions in the script and they work, why isn't this one working?

```
#so it doesn't work when I run it like this
remove_empties=function(fish8){
  fish8<<-fish8[!(fish8$BIN == "" | is.na(fish8$BIN)), ]
  fish8<<-fish8[!(fish8$collectors == "" | is.na(fish8$collectors)), ]
  fish8<<-fish8[!(fish8$country == "" | is.na(fish8$country)), ]
}
remove_empties(fish8)

#but it runs like this
fish8<-fish8[!(fish8$BIN == "" | is.na(fish8$BIN)), ]
fish8<-fish8[!(fish8$collectors == "" | is.na(fish8$collectors)), ]
fish8<-fish8[!(fish8$country == "" | is.na(fish8$country)), ]
```

Comment: We don't have your data, so it's difficult to tell. But the use of `<<-` seems error-prone to me.

Comment: The use of ```<<-``` seems fishy to me. It seems strange to have the function at all if you both globally assign and subset.

Comment: hum, ok thanks for the responses. but how should I do where I am changing the dataframe inside a function? because if I don't use "<<-" at least once inside the functions, the dataframe isn't changed

Comment: You can assign results to overwrite a whole structure rather than trying to update every time inside a function. Take `x <- 1:10` and then for e.g. `add1 <- function(input) {input + 1}` then you do `x <- add1(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the scope of variables. In this case, the function's variable `fish8` is getting assigned within the function scope. The original `fish8` doesn't get touched. See https://www.r-bloggers.com/dont-run-afoul-of-scoping-rules-in-r/ :

> What happens with <<- is that it starts walking up the environment tree from child to parent until it either finds a match, or ends up in the global (top) environment. This is a way to initiate a tree-walk (like automatic searching) but with dire consequences because you are making an assignment outside of the current scope! Only the first match it finds will get changed, whether or not it is at the global environment.

Your options include:

1. Remove the double assignment and reassign the results of the function to the original dataframe

```
remove_empties = function(fish8) {
  fish8 <- fish8[!(fish8$x == '' | is.na(fish8$x)), ]
  fish8 <- fish8[!(fish8$y == '' | is.na(fish8$y)), ]
}

fish8 <- remove_empties(fish8)
```

2. Using a different variable within the function which would be better practice than having the same variable name in two different environments.

```
remove_empties2 = function(fish) {
  fish <- fish[!(fish$x == '' | is.na(fish$x)), ]
  fish <- fish[!(fish$y == '' | is.na(fish$y)), ]
}

fish8 <- remove_empties2(fish8)
```

3. Change the variable name in the function but globally assigning the original variable. I don't like this route:

```
remove_empties3 = function(fish) {
  fish8 <<- fish[!(fish$x == '' | is.na(fish$x))
                 & !(fish$y == '' | is.na(fish$y)), ]
}

remove_empties3(fish8)
```

4. **My favorite option:** reassigning the empty strings as `NA` and then using `na.omit()`. I'd also forgo the function call - this at most one extra line than a function call and should only have to be done once as empty strings shouldn't be re-introduced:

```
fish8[fish8==''] <- NA_character_
fish8 <- na.omit(fish8)
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c('',NA_character_, letters[1:5]), 20, replace = T)
y <- sample(c('', NA_character_, letters[6:10]), 20, replace = T)

fish8 <- data.frame(x, y)
```